# MapFragment is not showing Map

Tags: visual-studio, google-maps, xamarin.android

I am trying to assign MapFragment's Map to google map as below.

```
  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Maps);
  MapFragment mapFragment =(MapFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);
  mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
  GoogleMap googleMap = mapFragment.Map;// here Map is not available
```

here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:entries="@array/maptype_arrays">    
  </Spinner>
  <fragment
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android.id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am able to see the map in my device  while commenting `GoogleMap googleMap = mapFragment.Map`, is anything else to add to get Map for fragment.

Manifest:

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" package="com.company.Mapsdemo" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionName="1.0.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
  <uses-permission android:name="Mapsdemo.Mapsdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <user-features android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
  <application android:allowBackup="true" 
               android:largeHeap="true" 
               android:icon="@drawable/MapsDemoAppIcon" 
               android:label="@string/app_name" 
               android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" 
               android:supportsRtl="true" 
               android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="@string/GoogleKey"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: First thing you should check is - if the API key is placed in the right manner. Can you please provide the screenshot of your manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the response @SubrataMondal, I have updated my code with manifest, can you please check it

Answer (score 0):

Please check if there are google_maps_api.xml.There will be two. One for the debug and one for the release. If you are deploying from Android Studio, then the debug key is essential.

[image: Image attached]

Comment: Thanks for the efforts @Subrata Mondal, but I did not find google_maps_api.xml and I am using visual studio.